# Проблема с аутентификацией/сессией Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть приложение в котором к любой вьюшке, кроме манипуляций с логином, прикручено требование быть авторизованным (LoginRequiredMixin).
Но на удаленном сервере возникает проблема вида, на мой взгляд, что на момент вызова вьюшки я считаюсь авторизованным, но при работе с шаблоном уже нет.
Вот что имеется.
[image: есть]

А вот что должно быть
[image: должно быть]
Непосредственно код:

```py
# вьюшка index из views.py
class CustomViews(LoginRequiredMixin):
    """
    Some custom general purpose views
    """
    def index(request):
        return render(
            request,
            'index.html',
        )
```

```
<!--index.html-->
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}
{% block content %}
    Hello world!
{% endblock content %}
```

```
<!--body в base_generic.html-->
<div class="col-sm-2">
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% block sidebar %}
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-left">Пользователь:
          {% if user.is_superuser %}[АДМИН]{% elif user.profile.is_moderator %}[МОДЕРАТОР]{% endif %} {{ user.profile }}</p>
        <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Выйти</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Домашняя страница</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'events' %}">Все события</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'user-events' %}">Мои события</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'account' %}">Аккаунт</a></li>
        {% if user.is_superuser %}<li><a href="{% url 'users' %}">Пользователи</a></li>{% endif %}
      </ul>
    {% endblock sidebar %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
</div>
```

Так же есть подозрения на механизм сессий, сервер на котором находится приложение(pythonanywhere.com), или вообще браузер

Comment: Хотите сказать, что на локальном сервере код из `views.py` отлично работает?

Comment: Пардон, выше не указано, но я привел лишь вьюшку а не весь файл, но не думаю что было необходимо демонстрировать весь файл с "имортами" и другими view, т.к это первое, что показывается авторизованным пользователям, и где встречается проблема. И да, работает.

Comment: Интересноя, конечно, у вас реализация view. Рискую предположить, что `LoginRequiredMixin` в ней может не работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы во `views.py` не передаете в контекст шаблона переменную `user`, поэтому все проверки в шаблоне с её использованием не срабатывают, и ничего не показывается.

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user': user})
```

Comment: Видимо, у него контекстный процессор не подгрузился